# How to get array with maximum value within array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which looks like this:-

```
    $my_array = array();
    $my_array[] = array("is_match" => false, "number_of_matches" => 0);
    $my_array[] = array("is_match" => true, "number_of_matches" => 2, "id" => 1);
    $my_array[] = array("is_match" => false, "number_of_matches" => 5, "id" => 1);
    $my_array[] = array("is_match" => false, "number_of_matches" => 3, "id" => 1);
    $my_array[] = array("is_match" => false, "number_of_matches" => 1, "id" => 1);
```

Now i want to get the array with maximum number of matches i.e number_of_matches. Like in this example i want to get below array

```
    array("is_match" => false, "number_of_matches" => 5, "id" => 1);
```

I know max() function but it returns maximum value in the array but i want to return the array containing the maximum value in number_of_mataches

Comment: `usort` it, pick the last entry or the first (depending on if you sorted is ascending or descending) of the sorted array. Or a simple foreach loop substituting the current 'winner' with another one if its value is higher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you truly just want the maximum `number_of_matches` element, then I think `uasort` is a bit overkill and may potentially take longer to execute (however negligible that difference could be.)

```
$max = false;
foreach ($my_array as $a) {
    if (!$max || $max['number_of_matches'] < $a['number_of_matches']) {
        $max = $a;
    }
}
```

Only limitation with this is that it will return the first maximum and no other. To get around that limitation (and this gets lengthier than a `uasort` but may still be faster than a sort):

```
$max = false;
foreach ($my_array as $a) {
    if (!$max || $max['number_of_matches'] < $a['number_of_matches']) {
        $max = $a;
        $max_array = array();
        $max_array[] = $a;
    } else if ($max['number_of_matches'] == $a['number_of_matches']) {
        $max_array[] = $a;
    }
}
```

Comment: He wants the whole array that holds the max `number_of_matches`, not just the max `number_of_matches`.

Comment: @MisterDood It still does that. Notice the `$max = $a` where the conditional compares the element `number_of_matches` of `$max` and `$a` respectively?

Comment: how do i get the array in the above code. like there is not echo in the above code. If I want to get that array outside foreach loop then what i can do

Comment: @JunaidRehman ... The array will be `$max` or the array of max arrays will be `$max_array`. Do with it as your please, if you want to dump them to an echo output then do `var_dump($max)` or `var_dump($max_array)`

Comment: I just put $max_array; before foreach and at end of foreach i use print_r($max_array)

Comment: @JunaidRehman `$max_array` wasn't necessary before the `foreach` since it redeclares inside of the loop every time a new winner is found (which always happens in the first iteration), but whatever floats your boat. There's no scope issues with loops (unlike functions.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php):

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a['number_of_matches'] == $b['number_of_matches']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['number_of_matches'] < $b['number_of_matches']) ? 1 : -1;
}

uasort($my_array, 'cmp');

echo $my_array[0]['number_of_matches'];
```

`$my_array[0]` will hold the array with the highest `number_of_matches`

Comment: I am getting following error

Notice: Use of undefined constant cmp - assumed 'cmp' in D:\xampp\htdocs\testing\check_max.php on line 22

Notice: Undefined variable: a in D:\xampp\htdocs\testing\check_max.php on line 24

Comment: @JunaidRehman Oops; the `cmp` is supposed to be in quotes. I've fixed my answer accordingly. Just change `uasort($my_array, cmp);` to `uasort($my_array, 'cmp');`.

Comment: @JunaidRehman Oh wow. I didn't test this code before posting it as an answer. Sorry. Change `echo $a[0]['number_of_matches'];` to `echo $my_array[0]['number_of_matches'];`

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with:

```
usort($my_array, function($a, $b) {
    return $b['number_of_matches'] - $a['number_of_matches'];
});
```